# How to remove image from the UITableView cell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

My table view looks in non-edit mode...

[image]

In edit mode...

[image]

I want to show a list image in the **Department Name** field in edit mode. It should be get hide in non-edit mode.

I added this image using the following code in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`..

```
if (isInEditMode) {

    UIImageView *listingImage = [ [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(275, 16, 13, 13)];

    listingImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listing.png"];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:listingImage];

    [listingImage release];

}

else {

    //Need to remove image from cell

}
```

Update `isInEditMode` *Boolean* value with respect to the click of right bar button(edit button).

How can i remove the image in non-edit mode?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (isInEditMode) {

UIImageView *listingImage = [ [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(275, 16, 13, 13)];

listingImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listing.png"];
listingImage.tag = 777;
[cell.contentView addSubview:listingImage];

[listingImage release];

}

else {
    [[cell viewWithTag:777] removeFromSuperview];

}
```

if `[[cell viewWithTag:777] removeFromSuperview];` didnt work try with `[[cell.contentView viewWithTag:777] removeFromSuperview];`

Try this and see if it helps

Comment: Also, including this code in the `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` works good...


`for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
  
[view removeFromSuperview];
  
}`

I'm just removing all subviews from the cell..

Comment: Why do you want to remove all the sub views and add them again. You might affect the performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom `UITableViewCell`, you could just add this `UIImage` as a property of that custom cell. And when you need to hide / remove it, you can access it via this property and hide / remove it.

e.g. `[cell.listImage setHidden:YES];`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But im not using custom UITableViewCell here. What should i do for clear the image?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[cell.contentView removeSubview:listingImage]`

Which will require you to keep a reference to the listingImage around somewhere - add an ivar to store it.

Alternatively, return a different sort of cell for each state, one with the image and one without.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. "Alternatively, return a different sort of cell for each state, one with the image and one without" I can not understand this.. Could you explain it with code?

Comment: See the docs on custom UITableViewCells http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7. Essentially in the `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, decide which of two custom tableview cells to return